# TooManyRedirects when using google's ip instead of domain name

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-headers, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl google search results, everything is fine when i use domain name like this:

```
import requests
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
requests.get('https://google.com/search?q={}'.format('movie'),\
    verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
```

But when I use the IP to crawl google:

```
requests.get('https://216.58.207.78/search?q={}'.format('movie'),\
    verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent, 'host': 'google.com'})
```

The error below is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in send
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/home/mohammad/myfiles/gitRepo/telesearch/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 165, in resolve_redirects
raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: There is a trivial solution: use "google.com". Is there a reason not to?

Comment: Because i want to reduce time-to-first-byte and crawl directly using IP address

Comment: I see no reason to believe that using IP address will be faster, because in the end google decides where to redirect you and how to deliver data. This may in fact end up being slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it by adding `www.` to your `Host`:

```py
requests.get('https://216.58.207.78/search?q={}'.format('movie'),\
    verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent, 'host': 'www.google.com'})
```

**Explanation**:

This is happening because you are using `google.com` in your `Host` HTTP header.

When google receives your request, it sees that you are expecting `google.com` in your HTTP headers, so they redirect you to `www.google.com`. But when requests follows the redirect, it sends the same headers that you asked for, with `google.com` in the `Host`. So the server redirects you again and so on.

You can also just remove the `Host` header, it makes no difference as far as I've seen.